# Why won't the Pay 'n' Spray open during the mission 'Drive By'?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I'm trying to do the mission *'Drive By'* on *Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas* (PC edition). The issue is, when I roll up on the Pay 'n' Spray, the garage door won't open.

I'm definitely at the right Pay 'n' Spray, as there is the big red circle outside the garage door, indicating the mission waypoint. I drove up in the same car with the rest of the gang members. I keep bumping into the door, cop cars are crashing into me but the door won't open.

According to a YouTube video I watched, the door is supposed to open well before entering the red circle. So there must be some sort of glitch.

Is there some trick to open the door?

Answer (score 1):

Pay'n'Spray won't open if the police are actively after you (wanted stars are present and non-blinking) when you drive up to the red circle.

Comment: By active, he means that they shouldn't be able to see you.

Comment: There is also a short time where they can't see you but you still can't use Pay'n'Spray.

Comment: Yep, but short. ~10 secs.

Comment: This answer should be clarified to include that particular mission. In regular (non-mission) gameplay, you can hit a Pay'n'Spray with cops literally right behind you. I've even had cops inside the garage with me when the door goes down, and when it rises, they just drive out like nothing happened.